# Каким образом организовать обновление ленты?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Каким образом реализуется обновление ленты как на ru.stackoverflow.

[image: "2 вопроса с изменеиями"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое - вам нужны *WebSocket-ы*
Второе - вам нужен сервер с *WebSocket-ами*
Третье - сразу готовой библиотеки для постов нет, но есть библиотеки, для работы с *socket-ами*

Сокеты работают на событиях. 
Что-то изменилось нас сервере? => Отправляем всем клиентам изменения
Я, например, использую для сокетов [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) + [socket.io](http://socket.io/)

**Клиент:**

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io('http://localhost');
    socket.on('new posts', function (data) {
        /* тут мы получили все новые посты, делаем с ними, что хотим */
    });
</script>
```

**Сервер**

```
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
/* 
   когда мы получает данные с новым постом,
   просто отправляем всем подключениям информацию, что есть новые посты
*/
io.emit('new posts', /* наши данные */);
```

Можно не передавать сами данные, а только говорить, что они есть. Выводить кнопку для получение новых постов, а уже при нажатии на нее кидать обычный ajax-запрос

Comment: Есть еще long polling, хотя он и нелюбим многими(и мной тоже), но забывать про него не стоит.

Comment: не обязательно через сокеты, можно обычным ajax запросом опрашивать сервер каждые n секунд. Как не крути, но сокеты не на всех устройствах будут работать, не забывайте про мобильный рынок.

Comment: @Invision, не так уж все и [плохо](http://caniuse.com/#search=websockets), ajax каждый n-секунд в 2015 году - только как план Б